# Pasting text into a JTable does not invoke my TableCellListener

Tags: java, excel, paste

I have implemented an ExcelAdaper class into an application to allow me to copy and paste between Excel and a jTable.

The class came from here http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077579/learn-java/java-tip-77--enable-copy-and-paste-functionality-between-swing-s-jtables-and-excel.html

In the sample that I have provided I can type text into the left column and the TableCellListener will copy it to the right column

However if I paste text from the clipboard the TableCellListener does not get called.
I tried calling fireTableCellUpdated on the TableModel but that did not work either.

How do I make the TableCellListener trigger on a text paste action into the column 0?

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.datatransfer.Clipboard;
import java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor;
import java.awt.datatransfer.StringSelection;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

import javax.swing.*;

public class SimpleTableExample extends JFrame
{
    private JPanel      topPanel;
    private JTable      table;
    private JScrollPane scrollPane;

    public SimpleTableExample()
    {
        // Set the frame characteristics
        setTitle( "Simple Table Application" );
        setSize( 300, 200 );
        setBackground( Color.gray );

        // Create a panel to hold all other components
        topPanel = new JPanel();
        topPanel.setLayout( new BorderLayout() );
        getContentPane().add( topPanel );

        // Create columns names
        String columnNames[] = { "Paste Text Here", "Should appear here" };

        // Create some data
        String dataValues[][] =
            {
                { "", "" },
                { "", "" },
            };

        table = new JTable( dataValues, columnNames );

        scrollPane = new JScrollPane( table );
        topPanel.add( scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER );
        ExcelAdapter myAd = new ExcelAdapter(table);
        TableCellListener tcl = new TableCellListener(table, action);
    }

    public static void main( String args[] )
    {
        SimpleTableExample mainFrame    = new SimpleTableExample();
        mainFrame.setVisible( true );
   }

    Action action = new AbstractAction()
    {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) /* Specific actions              associated with manual cell edits */
        {
            TableCellListener tcl = (TableCellListener)e.getSource();
            int row = tcl.getRow();

            int column = tcl.getColumn();
            if (column == 0)
            {
                table.setValueAt(table.getValueAt(row, column),row,column + 1);
            }
        }
    };

    static class TableCellListener implements PropertyChangeListener, Runnable
    {
        private JTable table;
        private Action action;

        private int row;
        private int column;
        private Object oldValue;
        private Object newValue;

        public TableCellListener(JTable table, Action action)
        {
            this.table = table;
            this.action = action;
            this.table.addPropertyChangeListener( this );
        }

        private TableCellListener(JTable table, int row, int column, Object oldValue, Object newValue)
        {
            this.table = table;
            this.row = row;
            this.column = column;
            this.oldValue = oldValue;
            this.newValue = newValue;
        }

        public int getColumn()
        {
            return column;
        }

        public Object getNewValue()
        {
            return newValue;
        }

        public Object getOldValue()
        {
            return oldValue;
        }

        public int getRow()
        {
            return row;
        }

        public JTable getTable()
        {
            return table;
        }

        @Override
        public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent e)
        {

            if ("tableCellEditor".equals(e.getPropertyName()))
            {
                if (table.isEditing())
                    processEditingStarted();
                else
                    processEditingStopped();
            }
        }

        private void processEditingStarted()
        {
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater( this );
        }

        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            row = table.convertRowIndexToModel( table.getEditingRow() );
            column = table.convertColumnIndexToModel( table.getEditingColumn() );
            oldValue = table.getModel().getValueAt(row, column);
            newValue = null;
        }

        private void processEditingStopped()
        {
            newValue = table.getModel().getValueAt(row, column);

            if (newValue != null && !newValue.equals(oldValue))
            {

                TableCellListener tcl = new TableCellListener(
                        getTable(), getRow(), getColumn(), getOldValue(), getNewValue());

                ActionEvent event = new ActionEvent(
                        tcl,
                        ActionEvent.ACTION_PERFORMED,
                        "");
                action.actionPerformed(event);
            }
        }
    }//TableCellListener

    public class ExcelAdapter implements ActionListener
    {
        private String rowstring,value;
        private Clipboard system;
        private StringSelection stsel;
        private JTable jTable1 ;

        public ExcelAdapter(JTable myJTable)
        {
            jTable1 = myJTable;
            KeyStroke copy = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_C,ActionEvent.CTRL_MASK,false);

            KeyStroke paste = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_V,ActionEvent.CTRL_MASK,false);

            jTable1.registerKeyboardAction(this,"Copy",copy,JComponent.WHEN_FOCUSED);
            jTable1.registerKeyboardAction(this,"Paste",paste,JComponent.WHEN_FOCUSED);
        system = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
        }

        public JTable getJTable() {return jTable1;}
        public void setJTable(JTable jTable1) {this.jTable1=jTable1;}

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            if (e.getActionCommand().compareTo("Copy")==0)
            {
                StringBuffer sbf=new StringBuffer();
                // Check to ensure we have selected only a contiguous block of
                // cells
                int numcols=jTable1.getSelectedColumnCount();
                int numrows=jTable1.getSelectedRowCount();
                int[] rowsselected=jTable1.getSelectedRows();
                int[] colsselected=jTable1.getSelectedColumns();
                if (!((numrows-1==rowsselected[rowsselected.length-1]-rowsselected[0] &&
                        numrows==rowsselected.length) &&
                        (numcols-1==colsselected[colsselected.length-1]-colsselected[0] &&
                        numcols==colsselected.length)))
                    {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid Copy Selection",
                                "Invalid Copy Selection",
                            JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                        return;
                    }
                    for (int i=0;i<numrows;i++)
                    {
                        for (int j=0;j<numcols;j++)
                        {
                        sbf.append(jTable1.getValueAt(rowsselected[i],colsselected[j]));
                        if (j<numcols-1) sbf.append("\t");
                    }
                    sbf.append("\n");
                }
                stsel  = new StringSelection(sbf.toString());
                system = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
                system.setContents(stsel,stsel);
                }
            if (e.getActionCommand().compareTo("Paste")==0)
            {
                System.out.println("Trying to Paste");
                int startRow=(jTable1.getSelectedRows())[0];
                int startCol=(jTable1.getSelectedColumns())[0];
                try
                {
                    String trstring= (String)(system.getContents(this).getTransferData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor));
                    System.out.println("String is:"+trstring);
                    StringTokenizer st1=new StringTokenizer(trstring,"\n");
                    for(int i=0;st1.hasMoreTokens();i++)
                    {
                        rowstring=st1.nextToken();
                        StringTokenizer st2=new StringTokenizer(rowstring,"\t");
                        for(int j=0;st2.hasMoreTokens();j++)
                        {
                            value=(String)st2.nextToken();
                            if (startRow+i< jTable1.getRowCount()  &&
                                    startCol+j< jTable1.getColumnCount())
                                jTable1.setValueAt(value,startRow+i,startCol+j);
                            System.out.println("Putting "+ value+"at    row="+startRow+i+"column="+startCol+j);
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch(Exception ex){ex.printStackTrace();}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am just guessing. You did not attach the listener in both constructors. You need this : `this.table.addPropertyChangeListener(this);` in both.

Comment: @UDKOX Thanks for the advise. I think the main issue is that the ExcelAdapter is calling its own TableCellListener and not my one. Simple mistake, but I'm not an experienced developer, so easy to make .

Comment: If that solved the issue, mark it as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ExcelAdapter class was not referencing the expected TableCellListener.
Although I haven't developed the solution yet, reproducing the issue outside the application has help me determine what the problem was.